# FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule not working

Tags: android, flutter, dart, notifications

I have this class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_timezone/flutter_native_timezone.dart';
import 'package:rhabits/APIs/Notification/notification_api_handler.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

class FlutterLocalNotificationApiHandler extends NotificationApiHandler {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _api;

  static const String _timeNotificationStartId = "1";
  static const String _nonTimeNotificationStartId = "2";

  static const String _appIcon = 'launcher_icon';
  static const String _channelId = 'rhabits_notifications';
  static const String _channelName = 'RHabits Notifications';
  static const String _channelDescription = 'RHabits\' Notification channel';
  static const String _payloadRecurringNotification = 'recurring_notification';

  late NotificationDetails _platformChannelSpecifics;

  FlutterLocalNotificationApiHandler()
      : _api = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  @override
  Future<void> initialize() async {
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    String currentTimeZone = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
    tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(currentTimeZone));

    const AndroidInitializationSettings initSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings(_appIcon);

    InitializationSettings initSettings = const InitializationSettings(
      android: initSettingsAndroid,
    );

    _api.initialize(initSettings);

    await _api
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestNotificationsPermission();

    const AndroidNotificationDetails notiDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      _channelId,
      _channelName,
      channelDescription: _channelDescription,
      priority: Priority.max,
      importance: Importance.max,
    );

    _platformChannelSpecifics = const NotificationDetails(
      android: notiDetails,
    );

    const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      _channelId,
      _channelName,
      description: _channelDescription,
      importance: Importance.max,
    );

    await _api
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> showNotification(int id, String title, String body) async {
    await _api.show(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      _platformChannelSpecifics,
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> scheduleOneTimeNotification(
    String title,
    String body,
    String habitId,
    DateTime scheduledDate,
    TimeOfDay scheduledTime,
  ) async {
    tz.TZDateTime scheduleDate = tz.TZDateTime(
      tz.local,
      scheduledDate.year,
      scheduledDate.month,
      scheduledDate.day,
      scheduledTime.hour,
      scheduledTime.minute,
    );
    final int id = int.parse(_nonTimeNotificationStartId + habitId.toString());

    await _api.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      scheduleDate,
      _platformChannelSpecifics,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> scheduleRecurringNotification(
    String title,
    String body,
    String habitId,
    DateTime scheduledDate,
    TimeOfDay scheduledTime,
    List<int> weekDays,
  ) async {
    for (int weekDay in weekDays) {
      DateTime toScheduledDate = getDateOnWeekOfDate(scheduledDate, weekDay);
      await scheduleWeeklyNotification(
        title,
        body,
        habitId,
        toScheduledDate,
        scheduledTime,
      );
    }
  }

  DateTime getDateOnWeekOfDate(DateTime dateOnWeek, int weekDay) {
    if (dateOnWeek.weekday < weekDay) {
      return dateOnWeek.add(
        Duration(days: (7 - dateOnWeek.weekday) + weekDay),
      );
    } else {
      return dateOnWeek.add(
        Duration(days: weekDay - dateOnWeek.weekday),
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> scheduleWeeklyNotification(
    String title,
    String body,
    String habitId,
    DateTime scheduledDate,
    TimeOfDay scheduledTime,
  ) async {
    tz.TZDateTime scheduleDate = tz.TZDateTime(
      tz.local,
      scheduledDate.year,
      scheduledDate.month,
      scheduledDate.day,
      scheduledTime.hour,
      scheduledTime.minute,
    );

    int id = int.parse(
      _timeNotificationStartId +
          habitId.toString() +
          scheduleDate.weekday.toString(),
    );

    await _api.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      scheduleDate,
      _platformChannelSpecifics,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dayOfWeekAndTime,
      payload: _payloadRecurringNotification,
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> removeScheduledNotification(int id) async {
    await _api.cancel(id);
  }
```

The notifications are not showing.
Any suggestions?

It is supposed to schedule notifications for a habit, but it is not working, I am not beign able to see any notifications.

The only notifications that I can see, are the ones sending using the _api.show.

I checked that the notifications are on the PendingNotifications of the API, but they never shows. I also checked the timeZone and it is GMT which is the one that needs to be.

Any suggestions is welcome, I don't know what to check in order to fix this. I tried to read the API code, but it is very complex for me.